# Xcode 6.1 linker error when trying to link PushKit framework

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8, xcode6

Today I updated Xcode to 6.1 and found that my iOS project won't link any more. This project is targeted to iOS 7 and iOS 8 (x64 armv7 armv7s). And I'm using PushKit framework (not available in iOS7) which is marked as Optional in build settings. Everything was fine in Xcode 6.0.X but now it's broken in 6.1:

```
ld: embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later (@rpath/PushKit.framework/PushKit) for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've already tried to fully cleanup project including derived data.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already filled bug on [OpenRadar](http://www.openradar.me/17647271).
I also reported that bug and got next answer:

> Engineering has determined that your bug report (18664818) is a duplicate of another issue (18328913) and will be closed.

So waiting until that's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW3), you can use `dlopen()` to dynamically link to embedded frameworks when targeting iOS less than 8.0.

Comment: Don't forget to dynamically load symbols